# Generating a swagger ui from a static resource listing?

Tags: java, json, swagger

Im trying to present swagger as an option to my team . And Ive written up a static json file which conforms with the swagger specification for a resource listing. 
Is there any way in which I can generate a swagger like UI (http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/pet)  from this?

I tried Swagger4J but it doesnt seem to do much other than parsing the JSON. 
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Links : [Generating Rest API documentation using swagger or any other tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209926/generating-rest-api-documentation-using-swagger-or-any-other-tool) (Doesnt help)
https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/